# Definition of the function for exponentially decaying weighted average

Tags: mean, exponential-smoothing

I feel really thick asking this question, but I'm afraid I don't really understand the Wikipedia article explaining how to do a weighted average with [expontentially decreasing weights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Exponentially_decreasing_weights).

I really have two questions, I guess:

- I don't see anywhere in the Wiki article an explicit statement of the actual function to implement, something along the lines of `exp_dec_avg(x1, x2, x3, ..., xn) = ...` I think the reader is supposed to infer the definition of this function from the details provided but there are gaps my unstatsy mind can't fill. *Could someone give explicitly state the definition for me.*
- More mundane, I was assuming that `exp_dec_avg(3, 3, 3) = 3` but my probably horribly wrong implementation does not return this. Am I right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A *weighted average* of any sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ with respect to a parallel sequence of weights $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n$ is the linear combination

$$(w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 + \cdots + w_n x_n)\ /\ (w_1 + w_2 + \cdots + w_n).\tag{1}$$

An *exponentially weighted average* (EWA), by definition, uses a geometric sequence of weights

$$w_i = \rho^{n-i} w_0$$

for some number $\rho$. Since the common factor of $w_0 \ne 0$ will cancel in computing the fraction $(1)$, we may take $w_0=1$ if we wish. The EWA depends on the weights only through the number $\rho$.  Moreover, the denominator of $(1)$ simplifies to $1 + \rho+\rho^2 + \cdots + \rho^{n-1} = (1-\rho^n)/(1-\rho)$, enabling us to write

$$\operatorname{EWA}_\rho(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \frac{1-\rho}{1-\rho^n}(\rho^{n-1}x_1 + \rho^{n-2} x_2 + \cdots + \rho\, x_{n-1} + x_n).$$

What makes these particularly nice is that as the sequence $(x_i)$ grows, its EWA is very simple to update, because

$$\eqalign{
\operatorname{EWA}_\rho(x_1, \ldots, x_n, x_{n+1}) &= \frac{1-\rho}{1-\rho^{n+1}}(\rho^n x_1 + \rho^{n-1} x_2 + \cdots + \rho\, x_n +  x_{n+1}) \\
&= \rho\frac{1-\rho^{n}}{1-\rho^{n+1}}\operatorname{EWA}_\rho(x_1, \ldots, x_n) +  \frac{1-\rho}{1-\rho^{n+1}}x_{n+1}.\tag{2}}$$

Although that looks messy, it's really very simple: the updated EWA is a weighted average of the previous EWA and the new value $x_{n+1}$.  *We don't need to hold on to all the $n$ preceding values:* we only need the most recent EWA.  Even better, usually $|\rho| \lt 1$ (to downweight the "older" values compared to the "newer" ones later in the sequence), which means once $n$ is sufficiently large, the values of $\rho^n$ and $\rho^{n+1}$ are negligible compared to $1$, whence

$$\frac{1-\rho^n}{1-\rho^{n+1}} \approx 1;\quad \frac{1-\rho}{1-\rho^{n+1}} \approx 1-\rho $$

to high accuracy.  With this approximation in mind, the update $(2)$ becomes

$$\operatorname{EWA}_\rho(x_1, \ldots, x_n, x_{n+1}) = \rho\operatorname{EWA}_\rho(x_1, \ldots, x_n) + (1-\rho)x_{n+1}.\tag{2a}$$

This rule $(2a)$ is sometimes used to *define* the EWA, recursively.

Now, provided $\rho \gt 0$ (which is very nearly always the case), it's straightforward to show that the weighted average lies between the extremes of the data values, so in particular

$$\max(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \ge \operatorname{EWA}_\rho(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \ge \min(x_1, \ldots, x_n).$$

When $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_n=c,$ say, then obviously the EWA must be $c$ itself (which is both the max and min of the $x_i$).

Here are some illustrations of how the EWA works.

[image: Figures]

At left is the $\operatorname{EWA}_\rho$ of $(1,2,\ldots, 10)$ as $\rho$ ranges from $0$ to $1$.  As $\rho\to 1$, the EWA approaches the arithmetic mean because all the weights $\rho^{n-i}$ approach equal values of $1$.  When $\rho \approx 0$, all but the last value ($x_{10}=10$) are heavily downweighted, producing an EWA close to the last value.

At middle and right are sequences of dots showing $x_1, \ldots, x_{50}$ and two EWA smooths: one for a high value of $\rho$, which downweights older values less, and one for a lower value of $\rho$, which--by downweighting older values more--tends to be less smooth but also closer to the recent $x$ values.

Here is an`R` implementation, via the function `ewa`, along with illustrations of its use to create the figures.

```R
ewa <- function(x, z, rho=1) {
  if (missing(z)) {
    n <- length(x)
    if (n > 1) w <-  rho^((n-1):0) else w <- rep(1, n)
    z <- sum(x * w) / sum(w) # Compute EWA from scratch
  } else {
    z <- rho * z + (1-rho)*x # Update EWA from previous value `z`
  }
  return(z)
}

par(mfrow=c(1,3))

f <- Vectorize(function(x) ewa(1:10, rho=x))
curve(f(x), xlim=c(0,1), lwd=2, main="EWA(1:10)",
      xlab=expression(rho), ylab="EWA(1,2,...,10)")

i <- 1:50
j <- i^0.5
x <- sin(j/0.53/max(j) * 2 * pi) * exp(j/max(j)) + (i > 300) + rnorm(length(i), sd=0.25)
z <- 0
x.EWA.1 <- sapply(x, function(x) z <<- ewa(x, z, 0.95))
x.EWA.2 <- sapply(x, function(x) z <<- ewa(x, z, 0.75))
plot(i, x, xlab="i", ylab="Value", main=expression(paste("x and EWA(x), ", rho == 0.9)))
lines(i, x.EWA.1, pch=16, col="Red", lwd=2)

plot(i, x, xlab="i", ylab="Value", main=expression(paste("x and EWA(x), ", rho == 0.75)))
lines(i, x.EWA.2, pch=16, col="Blue", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: this is more than I could have hoped for. I thank you and I'm sure many many others will too!

Comment: this is the most amazing description of EWA. thank you very much! simple. strict. concise. i ve read many. its very helpful to understand "linux load average".

Answer (score 1):

At the time that I'm writing this, there's a very unfortunate (and stupid, IMO) choice of notation in the section of the article you linked, where the symbol $w$ is used for two different purposes. In this case there's a distinction to be made between $w_i,$ the $i$'th weight in a set of $m$ weights, and $w,$ the damping factor. So when you see something like $w^{i-1}$, what you're seeing is the damping factor taken to the exponent $i-1$, *not* the $(i-1)$'th element of the weight vector. In order to alleviate this silly notation choice, I'll try to re-explain what it said using different notation.

Suppose you have a series ${\bf x} = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_T\}$ and, for some integer $k < T$ you want to take an $m$-step weighted average. That is, you want $$z_k = \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} w_i x_{k-i}.$$

One choice of vector ${\bf w} = \{w_0, w_1, \dots, w_{m-1}\}$ is one for which $w_i = r w_{i-1}$ where $r \in [0,1]$ is a damping factor. So the extreme cases are $r=0,$ which means you only take the last term, and $r=1,$ which means you take a straightforward sample mean of the last $m$ terms. Anything in between is one in which every time step backwards decays the importance of each term by a factor $r.$

In order to satisfy this condition, and to keep $\bf w$ normalized, we have
$$
w_i = \frac{r^i}{V}
$$
where $$V = \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} r^i = \frac{1-r^m}{1-r}.$$
An easy derivation of this last step can be seen [here.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html)

So $$w_i = \frac{r^i(1 - r)}{1-r^m}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If the ratio of any two adjacent weights is constant and not equal to 1, then the weighting scheme can be called exponentially weighted:
$$w_i/w_{i-1}=c\ne 1$$

For instance, $w=(4/7,2/7,1/7)$ satisfies this condition: $w_1/w_2=w_2/w_3=2$. Another example: $w=(1/13,3/13,9/13)$ satisfies this condition: $w_1/w_2=w_2/w_3=1/3$.

The reason it is called exponential is because you can obtain the last weight from the first weight by exponentiating with a base $c$: $$w_i=cw_{i-1}=c^2w_{i-2}=c^{i-1}w_1$$

The only reason your exponential weights do not produce exact 3 is that they don't add up to 1, but they should: $w_1+w_2+w_3= 1$. Another reason could be rounding, but I assume that you took that into account already. Any weighting scheme should produce 3 in your example.